# Show by counterexample that $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}^{+} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^{+} \times \mathbb{N}$ is false

Tags: discrete-mathematics, proof-explanation, set-theory

We are studying discerete mathematics and our professor has assigned us the task to give counterexample to the following false statement.

**Statement**: $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}^{+} \subseteq \mathbb{Z}^{+} \times \mathbb{N}$.

**My Issue**: My concern is that I believe the above statement is true because $\mathbb{Z}^{+}$ and  $\mathbb{N}$ represent same set of numbers $\{1,2,3....\}$ and hence L.H.S and R.HS of the statement represent same set. Since we know that each set is improper subset of itself, hence the statement is true not false. Am I wrong or the professor? Please guide.

Comment: @geetha290krm More likely $0 \in \Bbb N$.

Comment: It's common for the definition of natural numbers to vary from one course to the next or really in one area, specifically on whether or not 0 is included in natural numbers.
Most professors include a definition at some point in the beginning to everyone is on the same page.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, if $N=Z^+$ then indeed you are right since both sides are identical.

However, you might like to check with your professor if we are using the same convention, i.e. please check if $0 \in N$.

Just by answering that question, you could have came out with a counterexample if they use the convention that $0 \in N$.

Answer (score 2):

$\mathbb{N}$ is used in different contexts in different textbooks. Some use it for set of positive integers and some use it for set of non-negative integers. I think your professor meant the later. In that case, any ordered pair of the form $(0,n)$ where $n$ is positive integer, belongs to $\mathbb{N} \times \mathbb{Z}^+$ but not to $\mathbb{Z}^+ \times \mathbb{N}$.